# Creating Virtual Screen MacOS

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, syphon

I want to create a virtual screen on MacOS :

I tried Syphon: https://andreacremaschi.github.io/Syphon-virtual-screen/

but is there another way to do it programmatically to do it from Node.JS or electron?